# Reinstall CUDA toolkit

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

Okay, I've run this commands to install CUDA Toolkit version 10: (after downloading a .deb file )

`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-10-0-local_10.0.176-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-10-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda`

but then I realized I wanted version 9.0 and now every time try to uninstall everything from version 10.0 I just can't... 
When I run `apt-cache madison cuda`:

```
cuda | 10.0.130-1 | file:/var/cuda-repo-10-0-local-10.0.130-410.48  Packages
  cuda |  9.0.176-1 | file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  Packages
```

even if I try to install only version 9.0 making: `sudo apt-get install cuda=9.0.176-1` in the middle of the installation he tries to access 10.0 files

So I've tried everything! I just want complete removal of the 2 versions, the whole package, the key, everything so I can start from scratch

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove cuda*

then you should be able to download your package of choice without interfering.